# The difference between the Frequentist, Bayesian and Fisherian appraoches to statistical inference

Tags: probability, bayesian, inference, frequentist

I'm just trying to get my head around the differences between these three approaches to statistical inference. I'm just not entirely sure what the significant differences are between the three.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bayesian vs frequentist Interpretations of Probability](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31867/bayesian-vs-frequentist-interpretations-of-probability) but also see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232356/who-are-frequentists and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225002/are-we-frequentists-really-just-implicit-unwitting-bayesians and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167051/who-are-the-bayesians

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate, maybe even to more than one question.

Comment: See Geisser (2006), *Modes of Parametric Statistical Inference*; Barnett (1999), *Comparative Statistical Inference*, Cox (2006), *Principles of Statistical Inference*.

Comment: Also [What is the difference between “testing of hypothesis” and “test of significance”?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16227/17230). "Fisherian", it seems to me, takes on different meanings according to precisely what approach the writer wants to contrast Fisher's with - as Fisher was on one side or the other of most 20th C. statistical controversies the term needs to be used with care.